# average temperature of CPU

Tags: temperature

I downloaded the program named speedFan(for measuring the temperature of the hardware), and I have parameters like these

```
GPU: 60C
HDO: 38C
Temp1: 50C
Core 0: 44C
Core 1: 44C
Core: 59C
Ambient: 0C
```

I know that it shows me temperature of the different parts of my hardware, but I have no idea which ones, can You please explain it and also, is it something wrong with my laptop (because temperature of GPU is 60C) thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GPU is normally the hottest component in a computer, and it is spec'd to run the hottest. Generally speaking, 60C is well within spec for almost all GPUs. If you have a concern the manufacturers usually make the max temp public on the spec sheets for individual components.

GPU = Graphics Processing Unit (video card)
HD0 = Hard Drive 0. Your first (and likely only) hard drive.
Temp 1 is ambiguous and is usually a sensor somewhere on the motherboard.
Core 0 is the first core on your CPU
Core 1 is the second core on your CPU
Core with no designation usually stands for the CPU temperature at the IHS sensor.
Ambient is the temp around the case. This represents the lowest your rig can theoretically get to. In this case, you either live in Antarctica, or do not have that sensor.

Comment: what does it mean IHS sensor?

Comment: @lego - IHS is Integrated Head Spreader. It is the metal piece on the top of modern CPUs. It is the component that makes contact with the heatsink.

Comment: +1
IHS - Integrated Heat Spreader. Also see Computer Cooling on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cooling